# passing array to a method and searching for a key returns only the else condition

Tags: java, arrays, return

I am passing an integer array to a method and searching for KEY but it returns noo even if the key is present

```
class ArraySearch
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] arr={1,2,4,4,5};

        int k=5;

        System.out.println(findArray(arr,k));


    }

    public static String findArray( int arr[],int key)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            //System.out.println(arr[i]);
            if(arr[i]==key)
            return "YESS";

            else
            return "NOOO";//only this part is returned even if key id found
        }
        return "hoohah";
    }




}
```

Comment: It should work if you search for the first key (1 in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your code carefully.  You enter the loop, then test for the first element (i=0) if it equals the key.  If not (`else`) you return *immediately without searching the rest of the array.*

To search, you have to search the entire array.

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    if(arr[i]==key)
       return "YESS";
}
// if we get here we searched the entire array
return "NOOO";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String findArray( int arr[],int key)
{
    String status = "no";
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        //System.out.println(arr[i]);
        if(arr[i]==key){
        status = "YESS";
   } 
    }
    return status;
}
```